# Inserting html produced in r function

Tags: html, r, quarto

I want to construct html on the fly and have that html rendered
in Quarto.
The actual application involves inserting an iFrame,
but for simplicity, let's just make an `<img>` tag.

Here is my .qmd code:

````
```{r}
source("awash-functions.r")
```

How do you inject html text produced in an r function into a **quarto** document? 
In R markdown, I had the function `sprintf` a string. That doesn't seem to work here!

Here is `awash-functions.r`:

    imageLink <- function(iUrl, iText) {
      sprintf("<img src = '%s' width='24'>&emsp;%s", iUrl, iText)
    }

let's call the function and see what appears:

```{r echo=FALSE}
imageLink("https://www.united.com/8cd8323f017505df6908afc0b72b4925.svg", "united logo")
```

and now, here's what it's supposed to look like:

<img src = 'https://www.united.com/8cd8323f017505df6908afc0b72b4925.svg'>&emsp;united logo
````

It renders, and the function clearly gets called,
but it shows the html code, not the image:

[image: image of rendered quarto code]

I know it's something simple, but I can't find it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note:

- Firstly, Quarto by default wraps any code chunk output within the `<pre><code>` tag. To get the output asis you need to use the chunk option `results: asis`.
- Secondly, `sprintf` (or even `print`) returns output enclosed within quotes. So after using `results: asis`, you would get the html tags but would also get the quotes. So you need to wrap the `sprintf` with `cat` to get intended results.

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
imageLink <- function(iUrl, iText) {
  cat(sprintf("<img src = '%s'>&emsp;%s", iUrl, iText))
}
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| results: asis
imageLink("https://www.united.com/8cd8323f017505df6908afc0b72b4925.svg", "united logo")
```

and now, here's what it's supposed to look like:

<img src = 'https://www.united.com/8cd8323f017505df6908afc0b72b4925.svg'>&emsp;united logo
````

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million, shafee! And a note to any fellow-traveler Quarto noobs:
If you format the option `#| results : asis` it will not work! There must be no space between the keyword (results) and the colon.

Comment: Just want to add, The [new syntax `#| chunk_option: value`](https://yihui.org/en/2022/01/knitr-news/#an-alternative-syntax-for-chunk-options) is also available for rmarkdown since knitr version 1.35.